# How to use Oracle's APPEND hint with JOOQ-rendered INSERT statements?

Tags: java, sql-insert, jooq

I have a JOOQ query like the following:

```
dsl.insertInto(AUTHOR_ARCHIVE)
   .select(selectFrom(AUTHOR).where(AUTHOR.DECEASED.isTrue()));
```

I would like to leverage [Oracle's `/*+ APPEND */` hint](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/append-hint) to improve performance.

However, [JOOQ's documentation on oracle hints](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/oracle-hints/) does not include an example for `INSERT` statements. How do I inject the append hint in the above query with JOOQ 3.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints for DML are not currently supported by jOOQ, but are on the roadmap: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2654

In the meantime, your options are:

#### Resorting to [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/)

e.g. via [`DSLContext.execute(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#execute-java.lang.String-). Typically, you'd be extracting the SQL from the jOOQ `Query` via [`Query.getSQL()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL--) and [`Query.getBindValues()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getBindValues--). For example:

```java
Query query = ctx.insertInto(...).values(...);
ctx.execute(
    query.getSQL().replace("insert into", "insert /*+APPEND*/ into"), 
    query.getBindValues().toArray()
);
```

#### Implement DML hint support yourself

Via an [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) which patches the generated SQL on the [`renderEnd()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html#renderEnd-org.jooq.ExecuteContext-) event whenever some flag is set to true. You could put flags in [`Configuration.data()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Configuration.html#data--), for instance:

```java
public class MyListener extends DefaultExecuteListener {
    @Override
    public void renderEnd(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        if (ctx.data().containsKey("insert hint")) {
            ctx.sql(ctx.sql().replace(
                "insert into", 
                "insert " + ctx.data().get("insert hint") + " into"
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Configuration withHint = usualConfiguration.derive();
withHint.data("insert hint", "/*+APPEND*/");

DSL.using(withHint)
   .insertInto(...).values(...).execute();
```

Comment: The "Implement DML hint" option, worked for me. Just note that there is a missing parenthesis:

   "insert " + ctx.data().get("insert hint") + " into"
            ));